# React/Redux Can't update initial state / undefined problem

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to update my state and getting it to render.

Below I am calling my state from the reducer.js file and displaying the initial list fine.

```
<div className={classes.resultborder}>
                {this.props.transInput.map(data => {
                    return (
                        <Inputs
                            key={data.id}
                            xParty={data.xParty}
                            zParty={data.zParty}
                            yAction={data.yAction}
                            amount={data.amount}
                            deleteItem={() => this.deleteItem(data.id)}/>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
```

At the bottom of my parent app, I have

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        transInput: state.transactionInputs
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        submitResults: () => dispatch({type: 'SUBMIT', x: {
            xParty: 'Henry',
            yAction: 'Funds',
            zParty: 'Elizbath'
        }})
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Transactions);
```

I have hard coded my `submitResults` because I have not yet been able to update my state and display, this is for simplicity.

I am calling `submitResults` in a button

```
submitResults={this.props.submitResults}
```

Now below is my whole reducer

```
const initialReducer = {

    transactionInputs: [
        {id: 1, xParty: "statePaul", yAction: "Funds", zParty: "stateSandra", amount: 100},
        {id: 2, xParty: "stateEmily", yAction: "Loans", zParty: "stateJohn", amount: 200},
        {id: 3, xParty: "stateMatt", yAction: "Repays", zParty: "stateMicheal", amount: 300},
    ],
    emptyInputs: false,
    toggle: false
};

const reducer = (state = initialReducer, action) => {

    console.log(initialReducer.transactionInputs);

    if(action.type === 'SUBMIT'){
        return{
            ...state,
            xParty: state.xParty.concat(action.x)
        }
    }
    return state;
};

export default reducer;
```

When I press te button to run `submitResults` I get the following error message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined`

I want to be able to update my initial state and have it displayed (currently I do believe if I can get the initial state to update then the display will re-render fine).

I am not completely sure why this is not working but I do believe it's in my reducer.js file has something to dow ith how I'm returning my state.

I apprentice any suggestions.

Comment: `xParty` is not in `initialReducer` but rather it is a key inside of the `transactionInputs` array element(s). So this would make more sense `state.transactionInputs[0].xParty`. The error is correct, there is no `xParty` key in the object `initialReducer`.

Comment: Okay, is the error this line then ` xParty: state.xParty.concat(action.x)` ? How would I go about fixing it? I tried `  transactionInputs: state.transactionInputs.concat(action.x)` but it did not work.

Comment: Its hard to tell how to fix it without knowing much of your requirements. Based on what you posted `action.x` doesn't look like an array, it's an object, and `transactionInputs` is an array of objects. You `concat` two arrays, but concating an array to an object won't work. Changing `action.x` to be an array may solve your problem `x: [{
            xParty: 'Henry',
            yAction: 'Funds',
            zParty: 'Elizbath'
        }]`

Comment: @Annjawn thank you for your help, I have figured out what was wrong and answered my own question but I want to thank you again for your time, you helped guide me in the right direct friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the reducer.js file, under the action type of 'SUBMIT', I had the following code:

```
 if(action.type === 'SUBMIT'){
        return{
            ...state,
            xParty: state.xParty.concat(action.x)
        }
    }
    return state;
```

But I have that the bug was with the line `...state,` and now I have `...state.transactionInputs,`

```
if(action.type === 'SUBMIT'){
    return{
         ...state.transactionInputs,
         transactionInputs: state.transactionInputs.concat(action.x)
    };
}
```

***SIDE NOTE***

When I was trying to figure out what was wrong, I used `console.log(initialReducer.transactionInputs)` to see if the state was updating but I reliased that was I getting thr initial state and not the current one which was state. So for the console.log I should of used `console.log(state.transactionInputs);`, I would have solved this much sooner.

Just a side note :)